# Can I start tmux as a child of gnome-session?

Tags: gnome, tmux

I'm running Ubuntu and use `gnome-terminal` and would like to run `tmux` in such a way that it can use all of the `gnome-session` environment in the same way opening a new terminal window would. E.g. using passphrase-less ssh.

The issue seems to be the process hierarchy...

In a new window of `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ pstree -ps $$
init(1)───lightdm(1825)───lightdm(18486)───gnome-session(18552)───gnome-terminal(18626)
```

Once I enter a *new* `tmux` session (even in the above terminal window:

```
$ pstree -ps $$
init(1)───tmux(15798)───bash(21770)
```

`tmux` appears to be a direct child of init and not in the session's process hierarchy. Is there a way to get it to be created as a child of `gnome-session`?

**EDIT:** Great answer below (the accepted one)! However I thought I'd include a function I wrote since receiving the answer to update all child bash processes of tmux to the latest environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmup () 
{ 
    echo -n "Updating to latest tmux environment...";
    export IFS=",";
    for line in $(tmux showenv -t $(tmux display -p "#S") | tr "\n" ",");
    do
        if [[ $line == -* ]]; then
            unset $(echo $line | cut -c2-);
        else
            export $line;
        fi;
    done;
    unset IFS;
    echo "Done"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *tmux* server calls *daemon(3)* to detach itself from the process that started it (i.e. the initial *tmux* client). This is not optional so the server will always be reparented to PID 1 (e.g. *init*) after the double-fork-and-middle-exit done by *daemon(3)*.

In general, it should not be important that the *tmux* server is no longer directly “connected” to *gnome-session* though the parentage of (surviving) processes.

In the case of *ssh*, the ability to use a key without having to retype its passphrase relies on access to an *ssh-agent* process. Instances of *ssh* look for the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable to know where to contact an *ssh-agent* that can supply keys for it. *gnome-session* probably arranges to start an *ssh-agent* and populate its environment with the appropriate SSH_AUTH_SOCK value. This environment is inherited from parent to child as your various processes are started. In this way, the *tmux* server will also inherit the SSH_AUTH_SOCK value (from the initial *tmux* client, which got it from a shell, which got it from *gnome-terminal*, which got it from *gnome-session*).

A problem occurs, however, when you attach to a *tmux* session that was started from a different environment. Consider the following scenario that is hinted at by the fact that the PID of your *tmux* server is lower than that of your *gnome-session*:

1. Log in to a GUI session.
   *gnome-session* starts an *ssh-agent* and configures `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=foo` in its environment; this value will be inherited by all of its future children.
2. You start a *tmux* server (via a shell and *gnome-terminal*).
   The *tmux* server inherits `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=foo`; it will be passed on to its children (e.g. a shell running in a *tmux* session).
3. You disconnect from your *tmux* session and log out of your GUI session.
   The *tmux* server and its children still have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=foo`, but that value is probably no longer valid (when *gnome-session* is winding down, it probably killed the *ssh-agent* that it started).
4. Later, you log back in to a GUI session.
   This time *gnome-session* sets `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=bar` and passes it along to its children.
5. You reconnect to your *tmux* session.
   At this point, you have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=bar` “outside” *tmux* and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=foo` “inside” the session. This is the probably where you run into problems.

Effectively, since the *tmux* server has outlived the original GUI session, any environment variables it initially inherited that were specific to that session are potentially invalid (unless they happen to use exactly the same values the next time you log into a GUI session).

Luckily, *tmux* has a feature for handling this scenario. The `update-environment` session option specifies a list of environment variables that are copied into (or removed from) the “session environment” when a client creates or attaches to a session. SSH_AUTH_SOCK is a part of the default value of this option, so it is updated when you reattach. But, *tmux* is only able to update its “session environment” (which will be inherited by any **new** children of that session).

Unfortunately, *tmux* has no way to update any **existing** processes that are a part of that session (indeed, this is impossible, short of debugging tools that can tinker with the internals of already running processes). So, any existing shells running in windows/panes after the above scenario will probably be using an invalid SSH_AUTH_SOCK. *ssh* will not complain about the invalid value, it will just prompt you for the appropriate key’s passphrase.

What you might try doing is extracting the value of SSH_AUTH_SOCK from the session environment and incorporating it into the pre-existing shells from your old session with a command like this:

```
 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(tmux show-environment | awk '/^SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ { sub(/.*=/,""); print }')
```

If you are having issues related to other environment variables, then you may need to add them to `update-environment` (e.g. `set-option -ga update-environment ' FROBNIZ'` in your `~/.tmux.conf`) and do something similar to copy the values into any existing shells after you reattach from a different context.

Comment: Thanks! I believe you commented on another question in reply to a comment a made so thank you for that also! Great, and comprehensive, answer! As I replied on the other comment. I have since written a bash function to update the environment of a child bash shell to the latest that tmux has to offer using `tmux showenv`. The code is here: https://gist.github.com/4672606. Maybe you could include it in your answer since it will update all variables and not just `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` (which you correctly pointed out was what I wanted updating).